# Почему не выводит категорию, если нет данных в этой категории?

Tags: php, join

Есть скрипт, который выводит Категории (4 шт.), потом ищет статусы, присвоенные к каждой категории, далее считает, сколько лидов относится к этой категории. Работает все отлично! Но!

Вопрос: почему когда в категории нет данных, название самой категории не выводит?

```
<?

$query_firms = mysql_query("select ls.id, ls.title, ls.id_parameter, ls.drag, ls.url, COUNT(`l`.`id`) AS `rcnt`, (`st`.`id_parameter`) AS `param`
from leads_sort ls
  join status st on ls.id_parameter = st.leadssort and st.id_cabinet = ls.id_cabinet 
  join lids l on st.id_parameter = l.status and l.id_cabinet = ls.id_cabinet
where 
  ls.id_cabinet = $myrow_cabinet[id]
group by 
  ls.id
order by 
  ls.drag");

while($rew  = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_firms)) {
?>
  <a href="/leads/<?=$rew['url']?>" class="control-toggler__item<? if ($_GET['s'] == $rew['url']) {echo " control-toggler__item-selected";} ?>"><?=$rew['title']?><div class="kol_p"><?=$rew['rcnt']?></div><?=$options_leads?></a>
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: Так и должно быть, это inner join. Продолжайте изучать join'ы, вам нужно использовать left join.

Comment: Мне надо решить эту проблему. Т.е. если данных нет по выборке, не показывает  разделов вообще, а должен показывать просто допустим раздел "Новые 0".

Comment: Используйте LEFT JOIN при выборке, а конкретное поле на пустоту проверяйте так:

    IFNULL(field, "Новое 1")

Comment: Мне не надо его проверять на пустоту, мне надо, чтобы оно выводилось независимо от того, пустое оно или что-то есть...

Comment: В таком случае просто используйте LEFT JOIN.

Comment: И как это применить в моем примере? Я просто с JOIN пока плохо знаком, только-только начал изучать, но вот это решение уже работает у меня на сайте, и если не показывает группу, пользователей вводит в заблуждение.

Comment: Просто в запросе поменяйте оба JOIN'а на LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделал.